# "Enable Device Admin" Dialog not showing

Tags: android, device-admin

I'm trying to enable Device Admin when a user clicks a button.  However, the Device Admin never displays.  After debugging it, it appears that the app passes over the Activity without executing anything.

I tested on an API 16 and API 21 device, both above the API level 8 requirement.

Here are the relevant parts to my manifest:

```
<!-- Add Device Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name=".AddDeviceActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_add_device" />

<!-- Device Admin Receiver -->
        <receiver
            android:name=".AmayalockAdminReceiver"
            android:description="@string/txt_device_admin_description"
            android:label="@string/title_device_admin"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.device.admin"
                android:resource="@xml/device_admin" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

My device_admin xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<device-admin xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-policies>
        <force-lock />
    </uses-policies>
</device-admin>
```

My Activity:

```
public class AddDeviceActivity extends Activity {

private static final int REQUEST_CODE_ENABLE_ADMIN = 1;

    // Interaction with the DevicePolicyManager
    DevicePolicyManager mDPM;
    ComponentName mDeviceAdmin;

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_device);

        // Prepare to work with the Device Policy Manager
        mDPM = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
        mDeviceAdmin = new ComponentName(this, AmayalockAdminReceiver.class);

        // Set OnClickListener for addDevice Button
        Button addDevice = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAddDevice);
        addDevice.setOnClickListener(new AddDeviceOnClickListener());
}

private class AddDeviceOnClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        // Launch the Activity to have the user enable Device Admin
                Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
                intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, mDeviceAdmin);
                intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION, "EXPLANATION");
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_ENABLE_ADMIN);
}
```

My Device Admin Receiver:

```
import android.app.admin.DeviceAdminReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class AmayalockAdminReceiver extends DeviceAdminReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context, Intent intent) {

    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence onDisableRequested(Context context, Intent intent) {
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Inform parent of app being disabled.
    }
}
```

I was following [this Android tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html) to arrive where I currently am.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that you are not already an administrator? I don't know what `ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN` does if you are already an administrator, but I could see it possibly just finishing itself. [This sample app of mine](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/DeviceAdmin) has the same basic functionality as yours, and it works everywhere I've tried it, even on the emulator. In my case, though, I check to see whether or not I am an active administrator and only invoke `ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN` if I am not.

Comment: If I was an administrator, would my app show up under Settings > Security > Device administrators?  If so, it is not there.  I also added this code: `if (mDPM.isAdminActive(mDeviceAdmin)) {
                    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "I AM AN ADMIN"); }` Before my intent creation, but nothing appeared in the logs.

Comment: "If I was an administrator, would my app show up under Settings > Security > Device administrators?" -- if you're *installed* and have the appropriate stuff in the manifest, you should show up there, just unchecked. If you're checked, then you are an active administrator. BTW, in my prior comment, I linked to a collection of projects; [this is the actual project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/DeviceAdmin/LockMeNow) that I was referring to.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare, After comparing your manifest to mine, I noticed that I put `android:name="android.app.device.admin"` instead of `device_admin` in the metadata tag of my receiver.  Re-ran the app and the dialog appears.

Comment: Y'know, I looked at your manifest a few times, because it felt like the problem was there, but I missed that too. Glad you caught it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out in the AndroidManifest file, I put `android:name="android.app.device.admin"` instead of `device_admin` in the meta-data tag for the receiver.

Comment: Was this the only change you  made? I am running into the same issue, and have a similar setup as you. I still cannot get the admin dialog to come up from intent

Comment: can you share your code please ? I am also facing same issue.

Comment: I too having same issue and I have correct meta tag.

Comment: yes I am same issue. the dialog not showing.